# Appending a table from a XML object to HTML DOM

Tags: jquery, html, xml, dom

Can anyone tell my the simplest way to append a table from a XML to a DOM. So, i have a servlet that returns me an object like ddd and i want to append this result to a div.???

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xslt to transform your xml to html and append the result to your div.